# EJDB C# Binding

Tags: c#, nosql, ejdb

I'm having some trouble with the C# Binding for EJDB.

It's propably just an understanding issue.

Well I want to use EJDB to store some very basic Data. This Data shall be available whenever I start my program. (persistent)

I get no error running the code. It skips over the foreach at the end as the query.Find() returns nothing.
If you have a look at the comments, you see i do a query on "myCollection" twice. Once after I inserted data and once later in the second method.
The first count returns 1 and the second count returns 0. Indicating that there must be some datawipe between those two methods. My guess is the Dispose method, though if i do not call this the db does not get closed and i get exceptions when i try to open it again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Is EJDB only for Runtime data? Or do i have to save the DB somehow? Like a commit. Or do I close the DB wrong?

Now my code looks kinda like that:

```
    static public Data createNewData(Data myData)
    {
        var myDB = new EJDB("MyDB", EJDB.DEFAULT_OPEN_MODE | EJDB.JBOTRUNC);
        myDB.ThrowExceptionOnFail = true;

        var data = BSONDocument.ValueOf(new
        {
            name = myData.Name,
            guiName = myData.GuiName
        });

        myDB.Save("myCollection", data);
        //update ID
        myData.m_ID = data["_id"].ToString();

        //returns 1, => it worked
        int count = myDB.CreateQueryFor("myCollection").Count();

        //close the DB (as in the example, maybe thats the error? but then how to close the DB?)
        myDB.Dispose();

        //now calling the second method where the DB is empty again
        AllData.updateData();

        return myData;
    }


    static internal void updateData()
    {
        var myDB = new EJDB("MyDB", EJDB.DEFAULT_OPEN_MODE | EJDB.JBOTRUNC);
        myDB.ThrowExceptionOnFail = true;

        //just for testing
        //returns 0 DB seems to be empty, but i just stored the data in the previous method?!
        int count = myDB.CreateQueryFor("myCollection").Count();

        //get all data stored in myCollection
        var query = myDB.CreateQueryFor("myCollection");

        //this always finds nothing. the db seems to be empty
        using (var cur = query.Find())
        {
            //this foreach gets skipped as there is cur is empty
            foreach (var e in cur)
            {
                BSONDocument rdoc = e.ToBSONDocument();
                Data newData = Data.createNewDataFromBSONDocument(rdoc);
                AllData.Add(newData);
            }
        }

        myDB.Dispose();
        query.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops i found the error. *shame on me* One shall not copy paste from the example without thinking.

It was the Option  EJDB.JBOTRUNC  when opening the DB which just deletes all previous Data...